# What is the difference between Disk and Disc?

Tags: computing

I have come across both, but find it difficult to distinguish the difference.

Comment: I live in the UK, should I be using K or C?

Comment: `I live in the UK...` Go French on 'em: **Disque**

Comment: And then there's _Discworld™_.

Comment: What is the context? When referring to any flat, round object, *disk* is more common in the North America and *disc* elsewhere, but many specific uses have a specific preferred form: *virtual disk*, *flying disc*, *boot disk*, *disc brake*, *Golden Disk*, *Blu-Ray disc*, *floppy disk*, *flip disc*, *stellar disk*, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In computing, a disk is magnetic like an old floppy disk or a hard drive. A disc is a DVD or other circular media you put in your computer or other disc reading device.

Comment: Microsoft spells "hard disk" and "floppy disk", Amazon spells "compact disc" and "floppy disk"; so does wikipedia. Looks like this is the popularly accepted usage after all.

Comment: I have found exceptions to this rule but they are usually in older texts. I think it's a new wave of distinction.

Comment: I see [no justification in Google NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=optical+discs%2Coptical+disks%2Cmagnetic+discs%2Cmagnetic+disks&year_start=1960&year_end=2005&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coptical%20discs%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coptical%20disks%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmagnetic%20discs%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmagnetic%20disks%3B%2Cc0) for your distinction. It's just a US/UK spelling difference.

Comment: Here is a better justification: [NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=compact+disc%2Ccompact+disk%2Cfloppy+disk%2Cfloppy+disc&year_start=1960&year_end=2005&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccompact%20disc%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccompact%20disk%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfloppy%20disk%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfloppy%20disc%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 4):

[**oxforddictionaries.com**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/disc) says:

> Generally speaking, the British spelling is disc and the US spelling
>   is disk, although there is much overlap and variation between the two.
>   In particular, the spelling for senses relating to computers is nearly
>   always disk, as in floppy disk, disk drive, and so on.